# Restangular how to update item in collection

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I am currently fiddeling around with restangular and ui-router.

I do resolve a collection of items in my router which makes it available to the underlying controllers. I have a list of todos and i want to edit a todo. So i load a view where i can edit the item.

I get the model by `$scope.todo = todos.get(id)` I make a change to it and then i do `$scope.todo.save()` which updates the model on the server. But now i have the old item still in the collection of todos.

I want my collection to reflect the changes in the single item. I could delete the item from the collection and reinsert it afterwards, but this seems a little bit too complicated. Is there no easy way to update a model within a collection?

**Update**: Adding some Code

*Note: The todos property gets resolved if the state is called.*

If i edit a single todo i resolve it by

```
resolve : {
  todo : function($stateParams, todos) {
    return todos.get($stateParams.id);
  }
}
```

I do some changes and then i call `todo.save()`. No changes will happen on the collection this way. I tried to do a `todos.patch(todo)` but that actually did a request to weird url and i guess it is intended to patch the whole collection (?)

I am sure there is a way to change a model within a collection, but i dont know how

Comment: Re-inserting is usually not needed. Could you show some code? There can be many reasons for the missing update.

Comment: can you provide an example on how to edit an item from a collection? I searched the internet for hours now, but found no solution, but this seems to be a standard crud problem. I could always reload the whole collection, but actually the information is present

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying some stuff i ended up with replacing the item inside the collection. I created a little helper to lodash which i want to show here:

```
  var replaceItemById = function(list, element) {
    var index = _.indexOf(list, _.find(list, { id : element.id }));

    list.splice(index, 1 , element);

    return list;
  };

  _.mixin({'replaceItemById' : replaceItemById});
```

When i want to update a model inside a collection i do step by step:

Fetch the collection
Get a single item from the collection and edit it
Call save on the item

```
//The server returns the updated model
todo.save().then(function(editedTodo) {
  _.replaceItemById(todos, editedTodo);
  $state.go('todos.index');
});
```

This way i do not need to fetch the collection again (even if in most cases this is what you would do) and it is up to date after updating a single item.

Comment: Few days back i was also working on same kind of problem. There are 2 approaches to solve this-
1. On success you create a callback and update the complete grid, which will be very costly operation.
2. On success msg just update your local value with this changed values. To do this i was saving the complete collection in a map. And later when i get 200 OK from server i simply update the value in this map.